# What are Forward Blocks?

Tags: blockchain-fork, block-size-increase

[Mark Friedenbach](https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoins-block-size-can-be-increased-without-hard-fork-says-blockstream-co-founder) says "Bitcoin’s Block Size Can Be Increased Without Hard Fork".

Can someone ELI5 what are Forward Blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this week's Bitcoin Optech

> One well-known method for soft forking an increase in the Bitcoin
>   block size is extension blocks—a data structure that’s invisible to
>   nodes that haven’t upgraded to the soft fork and so is not subject to
>   their historic limits on block size. By itself, this is an undesirable
>   method for increasing block size because preventing old nodes from
>   seeing the transactions in the extension block also prevents them from
>   being able to enforce any other consensus rules on those
>   transactions—such as rules that prevent a malicious user from spending
>   other users’ bitcoins or from creating more bitcoins than allowed by
>   the 21 million bitcoin subsidy schedule.
>
> However, one doesn’t need to increase block size to increase the
>   amount of data that can be added to the block chain per minute—it’s
>   also possible to increase capacity by increasing the frequency of
>   blocks (reducing the average time between blocks). A method for gaming
>   Bitcoin’s difficulty adjustment algorithm—called a time-warp attack—is
>   well-known among experts and has been used successfully in
>   demonstration attacks against Bitcoin’s testnet and real attacks
>   against altcoins. (Note: although Bitcoin is technically vulnerable to
>   this attack, it’d be a slow attack that would give the userbase a
>   significant amount of time to respond.) By itself, increasing block
>   frequency is also an undesirable method for increasing capacity
>   because shorter block intervals increase the effectiveness of miners
>   with large amounts of hashrate and so is likely to increase mining
>   centralization.1
>
> Perhaps disproving the saying that “two wrongs don’t make a right,”
>   this talk describes a novel way of combining extension blocks and the
>   time-warp attack to allow both upgraded nodes and old nodes to gain
>   the same capacity increase and see all the same transactions for
>   validation while simultaneously slightly reducing mining
>   centralization risk. Upgraded nodes would validate one or more
>   extension blocks (called “forward blocks”) that provide additional
>   block space with a centralization-reducing 15 minute average interval,
>   but the upgraded nodes would also restrict the time stamps in legacy
>   blocks to ensure a permanent (but limited) time warp attack increased
>   the frequency of legacy blocks enough to allow them to include the
>   same transactions that previously appeared in the forward blocks.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8hJ0VTPE34&feature=youtu.be&t=3744) / [Transcript](https://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/scalingbitcoin/tokyo-2018/forward-blocks/) / [Paper](http://freico.in/forward-blocks-scalingbitcoin-paper.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, Mark Freidenbach refers to this work on Freicoin as the origins of ‘forward blocks’.

https://freicoinalliance.com/topic/638-changing-the-proof-of-work-algorithm/

Comment: No, that's orthogonal.